# How to position a h1 directly over an input and have it be for all screens?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

So I want to replace the text inside of an input field with a h1 tag as soon as the user hits submit because i want the text to have an animation but i can't animate the text inside the text field.

I linked the code pen project version of it to make it easier then organizing all the code in here. I added all the code I had so I wouldn't leave anything out although some of it may be irrelevant.

Basically I want the h1 tag to appear exactly where the input text was so it looks like nothing ever got replaced.

https://codepen.io/timvancowabunga/pen/rNOqdYd

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btn1').click(function() {
    $('#test').text($("#message").val());
    $('#message').val('');
    $('#test').val('');
  });
});

function onTextClick() {
  document.getElementById('btn1').className = "show";
}

function showButton() {

  document.getElementById('btn1').style.display = 'block';
}

function showSendButton() {
  document.getElementById('btn2').style.display = 'block';

}

function formCheck() {

  var input = $('#message').val();

  if (input == '') {
    alert("Please Submit a Valid Message");
  } else {
    hideButton();
    showSendButton();
  }
}

function hideButton() {
  document.getElementById('btn1').style.display = 'none';
}

function hideSendButton() {
  document.getElementById('btn2').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('sent').style.display = 'block';
}

function myMove() {

  var textWrapper = document.querySelector('.ml13');
  textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(/\S/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>");

  anime.timeline()
    .add({
      targets: '.ml13 .letter',
      translateY: [0, -1600],
      opacity: [1, 0],
      easing: "easeInSine",
      duration: 3600,
      delay: (el, i) => 800 + 60 * i
    });

}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #368670;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.ml13,
.ml14,
.ml15 {
  font-size: 1.9em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.ml15 {
  letter-spacing: 0em;
  text-align: center;
}

.ml13 .letter {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1em;
}

.line {
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 500px;
}

.wrappy {
  position: relative;
}

.wrappy h1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 48.5%;
  top: 20%
}

.butt {
  padding-top: 50px;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}

#btn1,
#btn2 {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

input {
  z-index: 1000;
  margin-left: 10%;
  width: 80%;
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  padding: 1em 0 .1em;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: inherit;
  outline: none;
}

input:focus {
  border-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.0.2/anime.min.js"></script>

<div class="truth">
  <!-- <div class="line"> -->
  <div class="message-box">

    <form class="message-form">

      <h2 class="ml15" for="message">TELL A TRUTH</h2>
      <div class="wrappy">

        <input type="text" id="message" name="message" autocomplete="off" class="ml14">
        <!--   <h1 id="test" class="ml13">I love your music!</h1>   -->
        <h1 id="test" class="ml13"></h1>
      </div>

    </form>
  </div>

  <div class="butt">
    <button id="btn1" onclick="formCheck();">Ready to Send?</button>
    <button id="btn2" style="display: none" onclick="myMove(); setTimeout(showButton, 3000); hideSendButton();">Send!</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: don't be sorry, simply follow the rules

Comment: What is   anime.timeline() and are you not supposed to execute mymove ?

Comment: whoa, thank you! I'm new to stack overflow so I was confused on the rules. anime.timeline() is from the anime js library. I included the cdn (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.0.2/anime.min.js) for it and it showed the animation in code pen but not in here.

Comment: I just addded the cdn for anime so the animation is working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to put H1 below the input.

Then you make the text input transparent. Bind the input value to h1.

So in effect when user clicks and type, they are selecting the input and changing its value, but it's transparent, to be shown by the h1 below the input that you will eventually animate.

Also because you mentioned you want it to display correctly in all platforms. You then have to be cognisant of the default behaviours of DOM and CSS properties. If you alter them to get what you want without knowing its natural order, you can get unexpected behaviour and reduce cross-browser compatibility. I have made changes to reflect that.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#btn1").click(function () {
    $("#test").text($("#message").val());
    $("#message").val("");
    $("#test").val("");
  });
});

function onTextClick() {
  document.getElementById("btn1").className = "show";
}
function showButton() {
  document.getElementById("btn1").style.display = "block";
}

function showSendButton() {
  document.getElementById("btn2").style.display = "block";
}

function formCheck() {
  var input = $("#message").val();

  if (input == "") {
    alert("Please Submit a Valid Message");
  } else {
    hideButton();
    showSendButton();
  }
}

function hideButton() {
  document.getElementById("btn1").style.display = "none";
}

function hideSendButton() {
  document.getElementById("btn2").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("sent").style.display = "block";
}

// attach this to bind h1 to the input value at all times.
$("#message").keyup(function () {
  var self = this;
  $("#test").text($(this).val());
});

function myMove() {
  var textWrapper = document.querySelector(".ml13");
  textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(
    /\S/g,
    "<span class='letter'>$&</span>"
  );

  anime.timeline().add({
    targets: ".ml13 .letter",
    translateY: [0, -1600],
    opacity: [1, 0],
    easing: "easeInSine",
    duration: 3600,
    delay: (el, i) => 800 + 60 * i
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #368670;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.ml13,
.ml14,
.ml15 {
  font-size: 1.9em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.ml15 {
  letter-spacing: 0em;
  text-align: center;
}

.ml13 .letter {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1em;
}

.line {
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 500px;
}

.wrappy {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrappy h1 {
  position: absolute; /* you then want to give wrappy h1 this to make it occupy no space. */
  width: 100%; /* to centralize the text, your option here is to make this 100% width and use text-align */
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 21px;
}

.butt {
  padding-top: 50px;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}

#btn1,
#btn2 {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

input {
  position: relative; /* in order for z-index to work, you need to give an element `position` attribute of value `static`, `relative` or `absolute`. */
  z-index: 1000; /* now this will work. wrappy h1 is not given a `z-index` so it defaults to `1`, hence input will be on top of wrappy h1 now. */
  width: 80%;
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000; /* you need the line back because we are going to assign color to be transparent */
  padding: 35px 0 0 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: transparent; /* make the text transparent */
  outline: none;
}

input:focus {
  border-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="truth">
  <!-- <div class="line"> -->
  <div class="message-box">

    <form class="message-form">

      <h2 class="ml15" for="message">TELL A TRUTH</h2>
      <div class="wrappy">
        <!-- for natural flow, you want to shift #test to above the input, so that input can stack on top of it -->
        <h1 id="test" class="ml13"></h1>
        <input type="text" id="message" name="message" autocomplete="off" class="ml14">
        <!--   <h1 id="test" class="ml13">I love your music!</h1>   -->

      </div>

    </form>
  </div>

  <div class="butt">
    <button id="btn1" onclick="formCheck();">Ready to Send?</button>
    <button id="btn2" style="display: none" onclick="myMove(); setTimeout(showButton, 3000); hideSendButton();">Send!</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much! I've been trying to crack this for a few days.